# Sending Message in SignalR from the Web API

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, webapi

I have created a hub in my Web API.  It is very simple:

```
public class DashboardHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(InfoSummary infoSummary)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", infoSummary);
    }
}
```

I am trying to send a message to the Hub from a controller in the same Web API when data is updated.

I have seen 100 different answers, and nothing works.  Basically my hub object in my controller is null, and I can't seem to get it instantiated.

```
    private readonly IRepository _repo;
    private readonly Helpers.Convert _convert;
    private readonly CoreContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly NotifyService _service;
    private readonly DashboardHub _hub;

    public MyController(IRepository repo, 
                                CoreContext context, 
                                IMapper mapper)
        {
            _convert = new Helpers.Convert(repo, mapper);
            _repo = repo;
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _hub = new DashboardHub();
            _service = new NotifyService(_hub);
        }

    [HttpPost("updatestatus")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateStatus(Header header) {

        var returnVal = await _repo.ChangeStatus(header.HeaderId, header.Status);

        headerSummary = _convert.ToReturnStatusHeader( await _repo.GetHeader(header.HeaderId));
        // await _service.SendNotificationAsync(headerSummary);
        await _hub.SendMessage(headerSummary);        

        return Ok(returnVal);
    }
```

I have the

```
services.AddSignalR();
services.AddScoped(typeof(DashboardHub));
```

and

```
endpoints.MapHub<DashboardHub>("/Hubs/DashboardHub");
```

in the proper sections in the startup.cs file

I know I am missing something very small, but I would love to know what it is.

I have also tried creating a strongly typed hub, but that introduced even more problems.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done there or four mistakes.

1. You don't need this line to be in your **ConfigureServices** method of **Startup.cs**. `services.AddScoped(typeof(DashboardHub));`

   Remove it. Just keep `services.AddSignalR();`
2. Why are you using **new** key word, since .net core provide in-built dependency 
   injection service. Remove below lines.

   ```
   _hub = new DashboardHub();
   _service = new NotifyService(_hub);
   ```

   Instead create a new interface **INotifyService.cs**  for **NotifyService.cs**.
   Register this service in **ConfigureServices** method of **Startup.cs**.

   `services.AddScoped<INotifyService, NotifyService>();`
3. Your **MyController.cs** should be like below

   Add this line.
   `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;`

```
    private readonly IRepository _repo;
    private readonly Helpers.Convert _convert;
    private readonly CoreContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly INotifyService _service;
    private readonly IHubContext<DashboardHub> _hubContext

    public MyController(IRepository repo, CoreContext context, IMapper mapper,INotifyService service,IHubContext<DashboardHub> hubContext)
        {
            _convert = new Helpers.Convert(repo, mapper);
            _repo = repo;
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _service = service;
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

    [HttpPost("updatestatus")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateStatus(Header header) {

        var returnVal = await _repo.ChangeStatus(header.HeaderId, header.Status);

        headerSummary = _convert.ToReturnStatusHeader( await _repo.GetHeader(header.HeaderId));
        // await _service.SendNotificationAsync(headerSummary);

        await hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", headerSummary);

        return Ok(returnVal);
    }
```

4. Use same concept if you are sending messages inside your **NotifyService.cs.**

Comment: Thanks!  I will make those additional changes.  I think those were from code I had found.  As I said, I had tried many things.  I prefer injection, and not sure why I didn't do it that way in the first place.  The big thing I was missing was the using statement (facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel like a complete and utter newb.  The fix is very simple.  You must add the using statement telling the controller you want to use SignalR.  OMG.. I am almost too embarrassed to put this up, but hope it will help someone else.

FIX:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
```

:facepalm

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is inject your hub using [dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection) in your controller. You can't just instanciate the hub in the controller like you are doing, and I would change it to a `Singleton` also.

```cs
services.AddSingleton(typeof(DashboardHub));
```

```cs
internal DashboardHub DashboardHub
{
    get
    {
        return this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<DashboardHub>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try that.  Thanks :)

Comment: ```services.AddSingleton(typeof(DashboardHub));```. No need of this line. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @BinaraThambugala this line is needed when you are passing the request to the manager, so you can inject the hub there.